# Compare source tree against git repository?

Tags: git

We have a post-receive hook that puts source code into a specific work-tree. Part of which looks like this:

```
git --work-tree=$ur checkout -f $b
echo "-- your changes were checked out to UAT: branch $b: root: $ur"
```

How do we see if someone has changed the files in this directory?

I tried this:

```
git --git-dir=$repo --work-tree=$work_tree  status
```

Changed a file, although the changed file isn't flagged.

```
# On branch 1.1.x
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

This does detect new files, but not changed files. e.g. a new file gives:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#    web/sites/what.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

git version is 1.7.1

Comment: This works for me on git 1.8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file I was testing the changes on was in .gitignore